# Cube not duplicating

Tags: modeling

I was working with rigid body cubes recently, and when I pressed <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>,  <kbd>Z</kbd> and moved it, and then I left clicked to do the action, but when i clicked it just snapped back where it was, and even if I try to move it, it snaps back again.

Comment: Has the cube you're duplicating some keyframes for the location? Or a baked simulation?

Answer (score 2):

You probably duplicated your cube when your animation was on a frame more than your starting frame. So whenever you are duplicating an object with a rigid body simulation always go to the starting frame of the animation and then duplicate your object.

[image]

But if your object has some keyframes assigned to it then the story is different and this is not the issue.